# Can I increase the size of the feature selection window of `WixUI_Mondo`?

Tags: wix

WiX. I use `WixUI_Mondo`. Can I increase this Window size?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is yes.

Long answer is that you will need to grab the wix source for the dialogs used within the WixUI_Mondo UI and modify the sizes of all the windows.

[Here](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/WixUI_Mondo.wxs) is the link to the WixUI_Mondo wxs file. You can see the DialogRefs used for this UI set. You can go up one level in git to look at the wixlib files and see that each DialogRef has its own wxs file defining the dialog itself. You'll need to copy the contents of each dialog ref into their own wxs files within your wixproj installer project and then you can modify the sizes of each dialog and realign some UI elements if needed. If you still need the WixUIExtension, you'll need to change the names of each dialog and the UI to not conflict with the defined UI and dialogs in the extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [localization files to change the dimensions of a control or dialog](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2012/07/14/localizing-more-than-strings-in-wix-v3-6/).